# Batch file - date variables and moving files with variable date file name from one folder to another

Tags: variables, batch-file, file-io, wildcard

I need some assistance, please. I'm trying to create a batch file to move files from one folder to another. The file name will have variable yyyy-mm format plus additional data before or after the date. The batch will need to move the file to a server directory with the same mmmm-yy folder name.

I've come up with the code below, but it doesn't quite work.

1. A "Missing Operand" error is returned.
2. The new directory is created but the files are not moving from the old folder to the new one.

My code:

```
@echo off

FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-6" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Day^,Hour^,Minute^,Month^,Second^,Year /Format:table') DO (
  SET /A MONTH=%%D
  SET /A YEAR=%%F
)

:: Set month to last month
set /a MONTH=%MONTH%-1

:: If month equals zero, reset to 12
if %MONTH%==0 set MONTH=12

:: If month < 10, fill with zero
if %MONTH% LSS 10 set MONTH=0%MONTH%

:: If month = 12, subtract one year
if %MONTH%==12 set /a YEAR=%YEAR%-1

SET FILEDATE=%YEAR%-%MONTH%

SET FOLDER2=E:\ARCHIVE\%FILEDATE%

MKDIR %FOLDER2%

:: trying to recreate the format MOVE C:\FOLDER1\\*2013-07*.* E:\FOLDER2\2013-07 which does work
MOVE C:\FOLDER1\\*%FILEDATE%*.* %FOLDER2%

:END

EXIT
```

EDIT: Both responders below really helped. I tried to vote them up, but I guess my reputation is not good. Mother was right - guard your repuation! It will get you far. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should better use `%date%`, not `wmic`, but you can try:

```
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Month^,Year /Format:table') do for /f "tokens=1,2" %%b in ("%%a") DO SET "month=%%b" &SET "year=%%c"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, that code produced more errors. .... '"SET month=8"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
MONTH=0-1
YEAR=2013....Also, The problem is with moving the files instead of parsing the date fields.

Comment: In addition, this batch file will be used by all employees and I can't be sure what format they have their system date set to. Research indicates the WMIC is safer in that instance. But thanks for your input.

Comment: I had a wrong double quote there. In your `MOVE`  command the asterisk behind %FILEDATE%  is missing, see Foxidrive's answer.

Comment: Thank you. That adjustment eliminated the missing operand error and the other one, too. I really appreciate your help. Now on to the 2nd part. =)

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor edit - it looks like it should work - as your explanation says the folder is being created just fine.

```
MOVE "C:\FOLDER1\*%FILEDATE%*" "%FOLDER2%"
```

Comment: Thank you, foxidrive. I made a typo in my original post. My code actually does have the asterisk (move C:\FOLDER1\\*%FILEDATE%*.* %FOLDER2%). But I added quotes around the two elements as you showed in your example and it still did not work. I also removed the .* after *%FILEDATE%* and it still does not work. Stumped!

Comment: Put a `pause` command after the `MOVE` line and tell us what error message appears.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The error message didn't really help, but I echoed all the variables again and it turns out the MONTH variable picked up a trailing space somewhere after the FOR routine. After research and modification, the trailing space is now gone and the MOVE command works. I really appreciate your help.