# Batch file: check name of day date, trim and copy

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy

I'm looking for a Windows CMD batch script that will check files in a folder. The files in the folder named as:

> ```
> 20150724_XXXXX.mp3
> ```

So you see, the file begin with a date, format as: `YYYYMMDD` (where `XXXXX` will be a name).

When the batch file find a file that will be begins with the date of the actual day, the file will be copy to a another folder. And the date in the filename is then cut from the file that only by `XXXXX.mp3` remains.

Comment: There are many similar questions, have you tried searching for `batch date file copy`? Here's an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18156110/3959875). On SO you must explicitly indicate why similar solutions aren't applicable unless you want your question being closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

set the correct location for `MP3_FOLDER` and `DESTINATION` and try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:::::::::::::::::::::::::
  set MP3_FOLDER=c:\mp3
  set DESTINATION=c:\mp3_no_date
:::::::::::::::::::::::::
pushd "%temp%"
makecab /D RptFileName=~.rpt /D InfFileName=~.inf /f nul >nul
for /f "tokens=3-7" %%a in ('find /i "makecab"^<~.rpt') do (
   set "current-date=%%e-%%b-%%c"
   set "YYYY=%%e"
   set "MMM=%%b"
   set "DD=%%c"
   set "current-time=%%d"
   set "weekday=%%a"
)
del ~.*
popd

set "Jan=01"
set "Feb=02"
set "Mar=03"
set "Apr=04"
set "May=05"
set "Jun=06"
set "Jul=07"
set "Aug=08"
set "Sep=09"
set "Oct=10"
set "Nov=11"
set "Dec=12"
set "MMM=!%MMM%!"

echo YYYYMMDD: %YYYY%%MMM%%DD%
set "YYYYMMDD=%YYYY%%MMM%%DD%"

pushd %MP3_FOLDER%

for %%# in (%YYYYMMDD%_*) do (
    set "fname=%%~nx#"
    set fname=!fname:~9!
    copy /y "%%~f#" "%DESTINATION%\!fname!"
)
popd 
endlocal

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the script below. Of course you need to adjust it to your needs but it should help you get started:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set mask=%date:~6,4%%date:~3,2%%date:~0,2%*

for %%i in (%mask%) do (
    set name=%%i
    set shortname=!name:~9!
    echo !shortname!
)
```

first you define the mask for the search. If your local date is displayed differently (mine is 24.07.2015) you need to adjust this line

the for loop enumerates all files that match the mask

since you want to strip off the date-info you have to first assign the for-variable to an environment variable and then strip off the first 9 characters. Note that you cannot do it directly from the for-variable and you cannot access the environment variable inside the for-loop without the enabledelayedexpansion setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wmic` command to get the current system date in a standardised format, like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem set source and destination directories to your needs
set sourcedir=C:\source
set destindir=C:\destin

rem get locale-independent date/time string (YYYYMMDDHHMMSS...) by "WMIC" command;
for /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set DAT=%%I
rem find files with today's date in name;
pushd %sourcedir%
for %%F in ("%DAT:~0,8%_*.mp3") do (
set NAM=%%~F
rem remove /L to go life (/L just lists what would be copied);
REM xcopy /L "%%~F" "%destindir%\!NAM:~9!"
)
popd

endlocal
```

Remove the `/L` switch to actually copy rather than just listing what would be copied.